# Defining 'missing' for colander.SchemaNode dynamically

Tags: python, pyramid

I have to define schema imperatively in the view because 'missing' needs to be dynamic:

```
    # ...
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=range)

    schema = SchemaNode(Mapping())
    schema.add(SchemaNode(Date(), name='to', missing=now))
    schema.add(SchemaNode(Date(), name='from', missing=now - delta))
    # ...
```

This is ugly. Is there a better way besides defining a custom type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [schema binding](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/binding.html).

```
@colander.deferred
def deferred_now(node, kw):
    now = kw['now']
    return now

@colander.deferred
def deferred_now_delta(node, kw):
    return kw['now'] - kw['delta']

class MySchema(MappingSchema):
     to = SchemaNode(Date(), missing=deferred_now)
     frm = SchemaNode(Date(), missing=deferred_now_delta)

def aview(request):
    schema = MySchema().bind(now=now(), delta=somedelta)
```

Comment: According to the docs [1] one can used schema binding for `default` attributes too, yet pyramid fails to fall the deferred function in those cases, causing a rendering error (trying to render a `colander.deferred` object).  How would one tweak your answer to use for `default` instead of `missing` ?
[1] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/binding.html